# Class is not recognized by DM when it is used with a custom dialog

Tags: class, customdialog, dm-script

There

I am adapting a DM script to read hdf5 file. there is a user defined Class called "MetaStr2TagGroup". It works well within the script.

I am trying to build a custom dialog to allow more options for users in a straightforward way. The custom dialog works fine with my test without the actual script part.

The problem happens when I put the script with class “MetaStr2TagGroup” to the front of my custom dialog script. It still runs to give a dialog and allow all the actions. But once I ask it run the script then it give me an error message "Cannot find class named ‘metastr2taggroup’"  But the class is still at the front of the entire script.

I don't understand that, Could any one explain me why it happens and how to avoid that?

My simplified code structure is like follows. The **object Local_helper** and **local_Helper = Alloc( Helper )** are what I've added according to BmyGuest's comment. It is not working so far.

```
Class Helper{
    functions1(){}
    functions2(){}
    TagGroup functions3(){
        Call function 1 and function 2}
}
Function4()   {
    Call function3()
}
Function5(){}
Function6(){
    Call function4()
}

class Converter : UIframe   {
    **object Local_helper**
    Action1(){}
    Action2()   {
        **local_Helper = Alloc( Helper )**
        Call Function6()
    }
}

TagGroup MakeFields1{}
TagGroup MakeFields2{}

//Main start here
Call MakeField1()
Call MakeField2()
object dialog_frame = alloc(Converter).init()
```

[image: Class error message when it is in a custom dialog script]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are running against is, that the "UIframe" dialog is created on a different thread. When a dialog button is pressed, the original "script" is no longer in scope ( Just the dialog object is. )

**So the following code does *not* run properly:**

```
class CHelper
{
    void DoStuff2( object self ) { OKDialog( "Action!" ); }
}

class CMyDialog : UIframe
{
    void DoStuff( object self )
    {
        Result( "\n Running method from other class: " )
        Alloc( CHelper ).DoStuff2()
    }

    object Init( object self )
    {
        TagGroup dlg, dlgItems
        dlg = DLGCreateDialog( "Test", dlgItems )
        dlgItems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreatePushButton( "Do Action", "DoStuff" ) )
        return self.super.init( dlg )
    }
}

Alloc( CMyDialog ).Init().Display( "My DLG" )
```

What you can do is to allocate an object of the second class right when you create the UI object. This can be done in the constructor method of the UIclass, or you can put the code into the Init() method as well. Now, this second object is in scope (because it´s part of the dialog object) and you can use it directly:

**This code does run properly:**

```
class CHelper
{
    void DoStuff2( object self ) { OKDialog( "Action!" ); }
}

class CMyDialog : UIframe
{
    object localHelper
    void DoStuff( object self )
    {
        Result( "\n Running method from other class: " )
        localHelper.DoStuff2()
    }

    object Init( object self )
    {
        localHelper = Alloc( CHelper )
        TagGroup dlg, dlgItems
        dlg = DLGCreateDialog( "Test", dlgItems )
        dlgItems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreatePushButton( "Do Action", "DoStuff" ))
        return self.super.init( dlg )
    }
}

Alloc( CMyDialog ).Init().Display( "My DLG" )
```

The alternative option would be to have the "second" class installed as a library. That way, it is *always* available for allocation. However, I would not recommend that solution.

Comment: I somehow understand your idea. But I am still struggling to adapt it to my script, which is complicated. probably need some time to play around and reading. I simplified my workflow as follows and added the local_helper and allocate it to the helper. But it is not working so far.

Comment: Can you repost your code example either as answer or (better) as an edit to your question. I'm kind of struggling to format it correctly? (Also, when any of your questions has an "answer" you like, could you please "accept" that answer by clicking the "check" so that it is marked an answered question?)

Comment: Not sure I understood your comment correctly, but it seems that you're mixing "classes" and "global methods" which is never a good thing to do. While possible, the whole purpose of object-oriented coding is to encapsulate all functionality in objects, except (maybe) the main method which starts the script. It is not a good architecture to have any class-method call a "global" method.

Comment: I am new to the forum so sorry that I didn't follow the right way. I just put my simplified code flow to my questions and checked all the good answers.

Comment: Honestly I am not an expert of coding. I learned all those DM script by reading DM help files and a handbook from Bernhard Schaffer when needed. Some of the content in the handbook is already very difficult for me to understand. I barely understand the concept of Class, task, thread and objects. If I have to use them I usually get a close one somewhere else, read it, test it and try to modify it for my own purpose.

Comment: @Roger Typical way to learn, and possibly the best: *Try-fail-ask* That's why I try to push this StackOverflow site. Your questions become beneficial for others at a later point too. I've tried some "extensive" answer below which is hopefully helping you. If other questions arise while trying to digest all, it might be better to open up new - clearly focused - questions rather than expanding on this one. In doing so, the Q&A stays more useful for others searching for answers.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, if this is getting extensive (the other answer is the "short" answer to you question and should possibly become the 'accepted' one.) However, I'm going to answer and explain the stuff regarding your example code here.

---

In a first step, I'm amending the pseudo code to something syntactically correct in [dm-script](/questions/tagged/dm-script):

```
Class Helper{
    void functions1( object self ){ OKDialog("F1"); }
    void functions2( object self ){ OKDialog("F2"); }
    TagGroup functions3( object self ){
        self.functions1()
        self.functions2()
    }
}

void Function4(){
   Alloc(Helper).functions3()
}

void Function5(){
    OKDialog("F5")
}

void Function6(){
    Function4()
}

class Converter : UIframe   {

    object Local_helper
    void Action1( object self ){ OKDialog("A1"); }
    void Action2( object self ){
        local_Helper = Alloc( Helper )
        function6()
    }
}

TagGroup MakeFields1(){ return NewTagGroup(); }
TagGroup MakeFields2(){ return NewTagGroup(); }

//Main start here
void main()
{
    MakeFields1()
    MakeFields2()
    object dialog_frame = alloc(Converter).init()
}
```

This code "runs" if you execute it, but it doesn't do much useful stuff. Is it more alike your code, though? Some of the changes I made are listed below with some general "object oriented coding" info, as you've pointed out in the comments that you might have not properly understood the concept. So pardon me, if I preach things you already know. (And I keep it simple.):

> - any method (except class constructor/destructor) require a return type, even if it is only `void`.
> - any class method requires a first parameter of type `object` which is the self-reference of an object of that class. It is conventionally
>     called `self` to reflect this, but that is not a requirement.
> - When you declare a 'class' with all the script code, this code is not actually used at all. Only when you allocate a new object (with
>     'alloc') you actually "create" an object which contains the code. Only
>     at that point does it actually exist in memory. If you allocate two
>     different objects, you have two 'different' sets of that code (like
>     starting a script twice), so whenever you want to call a method in a
>     class, you need to specify of which object the method should be
>     called! This is the reason for for the `self` variable in all the object-oriented coding.
> - I have also but the "main" script into a separate method and I don't want to go into details here, but you should know that when you create a variable of the type `object` on the main-level of a script, it will **not** get out of scope when the script finishes. The object will remain in memory! If you define it within any `{` `}` section, it *will* get out of scope once the section is finished.

Okay, back to your example. Let me first "optimize" some things. While it is possible to combine "global" methods, i.e. those defined on the main script level, with "class methods", i.e. those defined within a class, I would generally avoid it unless there is a really good reason. Generally, one aims at encapsulating all code which belong to one object into the class of the object. I assume that your "MakeFields" methods are to create the dialog layout of the UI? If so, put it into the class! I would typically do something like:

```
Class myDLG : UIFrame {
    taggroup CreateDlgTgs( object self ){
        taggroup dlg,dlgItems
        dlg = DLGCreateDialog( "Mine", dlgItems )
        dlgItems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateLabel( "Label" ) )
        return dlg
    }
    object MyInit( object self ){
        taggroup dlg = self.CreateDlgTgs()
        self.Init( dlg )
        return self
    }
}

void main(){
    object myDLG = Alloc( myDLG ).MyInit()
    myDLG.Pose()
}
main()
```

But then I would "simplify" it even more by not creating a new `MyInit` but rather keeping it simple `Init`. If my own `Init` method would have a different signature than the default `UIframe:Init` - that is if there would be any additional parameter - then the code would not really change. But if I use the *same* signature, I need to call the `parent`-method of the object. This is why the `super` keyword come in. It indicates that I do not want to call the `Init` of my class MyDialog:Init, but the `Init` of the parent class of MyDialog. So the code becomes:

```
Class myDLG : UIFrame {
    [...]
    object Init( object self ){
        taggroup dlg = self.CreateDlgTgs()
        object dlgObj = self.super.Init( dlg )
        return dlgObj
    }
}

void main(){
    object myDLG = Alloc( myDLG ).Init()
    myDLG.Pose()
}
main()
```

Next, note that the returned value of the `Init()` is the script-object self. With this - and with using the other returned values directly, things can be simplified to:

```
Class myDLG : UIFrame {
    [...]
    object Init( object self ){
        return self.super.Init( self.CreateDlgTgs() )
    }
}

void main(){
    Alloc( myDLG ).Init().Pose()
}
main()
```

Looking at the allocation line in more detail:

- `Alloc` creates me the object of the type. The command returns the object.
- To call the `Init` method of the class, one needs to use the the object as first parameter, because of the signature `object Init( object self )`. However, conveniently the first parameter can be written *in front* of the command separated by a dot. The following two are equivalent:
  `ShowImage( img )` and `img.ShowImage()` 
  Therefore the following is also equivalent:
  `Init( Alloc(MyDialog) )` and `Alloc(MyDialog).Init()`
- Now, the `Init()` method conveniently returns the object itself again. So we can simply "pipeline" the next command fired off from the object:
  `Pose( Init( Alloc(MyDialog) ) )` becomes `Alloc(MyDialog).Init().Pose()`

Also note, that I no longer have an `object` variable holding my dialog - because I don't need it in this case. Now, I no longer have the special situation of "the object on the main script stays in scope" to consider, so it is also fine to write it as:

```
Class myDLG : UIFrame {
    [...]
}

Alloc( myDLG ).Init().Pose()
```

Of course there might not even be a need to keep the `Pose` call out of the class. You can encapsulate all like in:

```
Class myDLG : UIFrame {
    [...]

    void RunAll( object self ) {
    self.Init().Pose()
    }
}

Alloc( myDLG ).RunAll()
```

---

> Without looking at your actual code, I can't advise what you need to do exactly. But most likely you want to incorporate `Function4`, `Function5` and `Function6` in a similar manner into either the Helper or the Converter class of yours. I assume it goes into the 'Helper' class here.

This will make your pseudo code into:

```
Class Helper{
    void functions1( object self ){ OKDialog("F1"); }
    void functions2( object self ){ OKDialog("F2"); }
    TagGroup functions3( object self ){
        self.functions1()
        self.functions2()
    }
    void Function4( object self ){
        self.functions3()
    }
    void functions5( object self ){ OKDialog("F5"); }
    void Function6( object self ){
        self.function4()
    }
}

class Converter : UIframe   {

    object Local_helper
    void Action1( object self ){ OKDialog("A1"); }
    void Action2( object self ){
        local_Helper = Alloc( Helper )
        local_Helper.function6()
    }
    TagGroup MakeFields1( object self ){
        return NewTagGroup(); 
    }
    TagGroup MakeFields2( object self ){ 
        return NewTagGroup(); 
    }
}

//Main start here
void main()
{
    object dialog_frame = alloc(Converter)
    dialog_frame.MakeFields1()
    dialog_frame.MakeFields2()
    dialog_frame.init()
}
```

And now we finally return to the original question. I assume that your `Action1` method is the one triggered by pushing a button? You can no longer allocate the helper class at that point - because this method is invoked when the dialog object sits in memory with no information about the original source-code (outside its class). Essentially, what happens is:

> 1) Script is executed
>
> 2) All source code is "run" on the main level. Objects are created
>
> 3) The dialog is displayed (The dialog object stays in memory as long
>   as the dialog is open)
>
> 4) The script code ends.
>
> 5) All objects (images etc.) not somehow 'anchored' in memory (f.e. by
>   being displayed) get removed from memory. The "complete source code" of the script also is no longer in memory.
>
> 6) You *now* press the button.
>
> 7) The dialog-invoked method tries to allocate code, which no longer is in memory.

To overcome this, you need to do what I was suggesting in the first answer: **Allocate the Helper object while the script-source-code is still available, i.e. during the Init() stage, but *not* in a method which is invoked later.** You then have your Helper object as a member of the dialog object, so it stays available and can be called. You can *not* keep a general 'global' method available like this. That's why you always want to encapsulate *all* code in objects and don't use global methods or variables at all. If there is a real *need* for such global methods, then you have to install them as libraries of DM so that they are always available.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining all those details. That's very helpful and indeed intensive. it will take me some time to read and digest those tutorial. I will feedback once I am done or still with questions.Best wishes.